# MySQLi Blank Page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert some data into a MySQL database using MySQLi, I have connected to the database but the page is just blank and the MySQL database is empty. Any ideas?

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', '***', '***', '***');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

session_start();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO membersinfo VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $_SESSION['fullname'],     $_SESSION['sex'], $_SESSION['dob'], $_SESSION['nameofparent'],     $_SESSION['address1'], $_SESSION['address2'], $_SESSION['city'], $_SESSION['postcode'], $_SESSION['homephone'], $_SESSION['mobilephone'] ,$_SESSION['workphone'], $_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['email2'], $_SESSION['contactname'], $_SESSION['relation'], $_SESSION['phonenumber'], $_SESSION['med'], $_SESSION['disability'], $_SESSION['typeofdis'], $_SESSION['natureofdis'], $_SESSION['sport'], $_SESSION['wheresport'], $_SESSION['friends'], $_SESSION['sign1'], $_SESSION['con1'], $_SESSION['date1'], $_SESSION['sign2'], $_SESSION['con2'], $_SESSION['date2'],$_POST['sign3'], $_POST['con3'], $_POST['date3']);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: $init = $mysqli->init(); just before $stmt

Comment: instead of bindParams use stmt->execute(array('all your bindParam value'));

Answer (score 0):

You have 32 ? And 33 values. Therefore you are getting the following mysql error or similar,

```
MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count
```

If you want to see the error please include this in your code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: I'm not getting that error message, and when I included that snippet of code to the top of my page, there are no error messages

Comment: I still counting 32 ? and 33 values, please add one more ? Or remove one value

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/nahadigital/public_html/rccdemo/signup/db.php on line 14